# Reading hexadecimal or reversed hexadecimal from card reader

Tags: c#, .net-core, card, cardreader

I have problem with reading card uid. I'm using C# .NetCore. Sometimes reader returns hexadecimal value and this is not problem, but problem is when some readers returning reversed hexadecimal value. Is there any indicator how to find is this value reversed or not?

Comment: Can you show examples of normal and reversed values?

Comment: 49 96 02 D2 is normal hexa value but D2 02 96 49 is reversed, normal hexa in decimal is 1234567890 but reversed is 3523384905 which is not ok. Reader to reader, some reads hexa, some reverse hexa and I can't know if is reversed or not just by reading it.

Comment: Just to be clear, will the same reader return normal and reversed values. or do you mean that some readers return normal and others return reversed. If it's the latter it could be set as part of the config, when running your app.

Comment: Well some readers are returning normal, some reversed, and I can't know what reader client have. UID number of card is something messed up, so there is no way that I can know is readed value normal or not.

Comment: Can you check the reader type in code and set the mode based on that?

Comment: So, there is problem, I don't know is there any options to check if reader read normal or reverse, and there is so much readers in market...

Comment: Then i don't see any other option than to make it configurable and have the client choose between normal/reversed when installing the component